# Disable automatic connection to weblogin networks

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, drm, motorola-razr-i

As far as I know, Android never had the option to disable automatic connection to specific Wifi networks, and always, stupidly, makes Wifi higher priority than 3G. Yet this kind of feature is *crucial* in urban areas with abundant open *web login* networks in cafés etc. Even Symbian on my old Nokia 5800 XpressMusic had the option to order networks manually, so that 3G could have higher priority than certain Wifi networks. iOS6, as a worse substitute of this ordering, also used to have the option to disable automatic connection to specific wifi networks. But that is gone since iOS7, so switching to Apple does not solve my problem. Has anyone figured out a hack, a third party app or so, to get this crucial feature on Android phones?

(I currently have Motorola RAZRi, and am extremely frustrated, since the one and only Jelly Bean upgrade 1.5 years ago made it unrootable and slow, and Motorola has provided no upgrades since then. I'm also frustrated by Android's region locking, not allowing me to install my bank's app while living abroad. Since iOS region locking -- while still evil like all DRM -- is softer, only based on the AppleID account, not the device itself, I'm considering switching to iPhone unless this Wifi issue can be solved more satisfactorily on Android.)

Internet searches turn up nothing, only other questions of the same fact, and answers saying "the asker is an idiot and this is standard behaviour on all mobile devices and how things should be". Maybe this attitude stems from different culture -- the US culture from where the tech companies offering substandard products come from -- where there are perhaps few weblogin networks? But in Europe the situation is different. It is frustrating to have internet stop working on the street, because instead of 3G, the phone has connected to a web login network radiating from the nearby café, e.g., the very common _TheCloud in the UK. At the same time, having wifi enabled is crucial, because even at my home in the centre of an important university town there is in practise no 3G -- not to even speak of LTE, for which I would not pay on this island that has worse signal quality than the third-world countries I've visited. In many cafés in particular there is no 3G reception, and a frequent need to use _TheCloud. The option of manually forgetting a network after each use is a purely unusable alternative, moving the task of *remembering* from the device to the user – yet IT should ease our lives, and have an option that needs to be set only once and forgot!

Comment: It's not only android, but the banks don't want people outside their zones to try logging in, as it makes it easier for intruders to try to access accounts. If my bank (which operates exclusively in Canada) started seeing logins from around the world for my account, they'd likely be paranoid and block the connection anyways. Not all do, but food for thought

Comment: I may misunderstand, but my android never automatically connects to any AP I have not accepted previously.

Comment: The whole point is to not automatically join networks I *do* occasionally, even frequently, use, but that require weblogin. The phone should not have internet randomly disabled on the street, whenever one of these rather ubiquitous networks is in range, until I *manually* disable wifi (usual solution), *manually* forget the same network for the 1000th time, or *manually* web-login.

Comment: The phone should *remember*, not *forget*, that I don't want to join automatically a network that I sometimes use, but that is *disabled* until further actions (web login). I should not be required to *remember to forget* every time I use the network. It is the job of the device, to do this kind of manual tasks for me, to help my life.

Comment: Fair enough. I really misunderstood.